# SQL: how to easily move deleted rows to another table with a trigger

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TRASH_EMPLOYEE AS
    SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE 1=0;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_02
BEFORE DELETE ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TRASH_EMPLOYEE 
    VALUES (:OLD.EMP_ID, :OLD.EMP_NAME, :OLD.EMP_NO, :OLD.EMAIL,
            :OLD.PHONE, :OLD.DEPT_CODE, :OLD.JOB_CODE,
            :OLD.SAL_LEVEL, :OLD.SALARY, :OLD.BONUS,
            :OLD.MANAGER_ID, :OLD.HIRE_DATE, :OLD.ENT_DATE, :OLD.ENT_YN);
--       (
--            SELECT * 
--            FROM EMPLOYEE
--            WHERE EMP_ID = :OLD.EMP_ID 
--            );
--         
END;
/
DELETE EMPLOYEE
    WHERE EMP_NAME='Anne';
SELECT * FROM TRASH_EMPLOYEE;
```

I am trying to move any rows that get deleted to another table using a trigger. But the commented out code doesn't work for me.

Is there any way other than what I did above (writing all the column)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because it tries to select from table which is just being modified, i.e. it is "mutating".

The right way to do it is what you already probably know - `INSERT` values you're deleting, referenced by the `:old` pseudorecord.

Comment: Thank you very much! So you'd say that's not a good way to manage database, right?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure I understand what is "that"? If you mean "storing deleted rows into another table", then that *is* the way to do it. If you mean "selecting from a mutating table", then yes - that's not a good way to do it.